# Check if date String contains a year

Tags: java, android, date

I have two Strings

```
String withYear = "12/04/1988"

String withoutYear = "10/04"
```

The date format is MM/dd/yyyy

I am trying to determine whether a string **contains a year or not**.

Here is my code so far :

```
Calendar c= Calendar.getInstance();
c.setTime(dt.parse(withYear)); //dt is a SimpleDateFormat 'MM/dd/yyyy'
c.get(Calendar.YEAR) // = 1988

c.setTime(dt.parse(withoutYear));
c.get(Calendar.YEAR);// = 1970
```

Comment: Are they both are fixed in in format ?

Comment: no exceptions the date format is right.

Comment: `if(myDateStr.split("/").length == 3)`, assuming this is a fixed format.

Comment: @Geobits could be a good workaround, is there any better way to check it with the Date object ? or the Calendar object?

Comment: If you want to use the Date/Calendar objects, what's wrong with what you have?

Comment: @OP you would have to know which format it's in to construct the Calendar object. Your suggestion looks like circular logic ;)

Comment: @user1940676 Since it is date related ,using calendar is not only the good way to do. Consider it as a string ,if the both are fixed in format. Make the life easy.Use Geobites solution.

Comment: When your input String is 10/04 and DateFormatter is MM/dd/yyyy, parse call should throw exception, I am surprised why it is not throwing exception, I might be missing something.

Comment: @Nambari my bad, I am checking if there is an exception and then trying to parse it with the second format without the year, it could be the solution as well.

Comment: @user1940676: That is the solution. I wouldn't go for any String parsing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the easiest way to do this is to forget about making Date/Calendar objects altogether. You can simply check the String to see how many sections it has:

```
public static boolean containsYear(String dateStr){
    return dateStr.split("/").length == 3;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Your code is working perfectly, when you call dt.parse(withoutYear), the year is set automatically to the Epoch year (1970).

From SimpleDateFormat: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

> This parsing operation uses the calendar to produce a Date. All of the
>   calendar's date-time fields are cleared before parsing, and the
>   calendar's default values of the date-time fields are used for any
>   missing date-time information. **For example, the year value of the
>   parsed Date is 1970 with GregorianCalendar if no year value is given
>   from the parsing operation.** (emphasis mine)

If you don't expect any valid year values as 1970 then you can assume all dates with year==1970 were specified without a year.

A more complete solution would be  to subclass GregorianCalendar and make the default value for field `YEAR = -1;`

Answer (score 2):

```
        String data[] = withYear.split("/");
        String year =null ;
        if(data.length==3){
            year = data[2] ;
            System.out.println(year);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want, you can use YodaTime, its very easy to deal with time/dates, more about it here [Yoda time getYear()](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/base/AbstractDateTime.html#getYear%28%29). You can try to parse your String and then getYear().

Hope this helps.